# ¿Cómo puedo ingresar números decimales a Python?

Tags: python

Tengo tres (03) entradas, las cuales son:

```py
xi = int(input('Introduce el valor de xi'))
xs = int(input('Introduce el valor de xs'))
error = int(input('Introduce el error'))
```

Pero, en ninguna puedo ingresar números decimales ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Al Ingresar un número decimal en cualquier de las tres (03) entradas surge el error antes descrito.

Comment: Hola Claudio, bienvenido a [es.so]. No se si entiendo tu problema, si quieres poder ingresar decimales haz el casting de la cadena ingresada a `float` y no a `int`, es decir: `xi = float(input('Introduce ....'))` simplemente. Obviamente `"3.5"` (por ejemplo) no es un literal válido para `int`, por lo que obtendrás un ValueError.

Comment: muchas gracias, era todo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 3):

## Tipos de variables

## Variable tipo entero

```
    entero = int(input("Ingresa un numero entero"))
    print(entero)
```

## Variable tipo flotante o decimal

```
    decimal = float(input("Ingresa un numero decimal"))
    print(decimal)
```

Comment: Existen varias tipos de variables tales como enteros, decimales, texto o boleano. Pero en este caso me centre en entero y decimal para los cuales se usa "int" y "float" respectivamente.

Comment: Mala idea user floats como decimales... Si el software se utiliza para calculos exactos, los float pueden fallar.

Answer (score 1):

Python tiene su propia librería **Decimal** para estas situaciones.

```
from decimal import Decimal

number = Decimal(input("Ingresa un valor decimal: "))
print(number)
```

Es cierto que mucha gente utiliza floats para calculos decimales, y puede ser suficiente para calculos simples; pero en mi opinión eso es un error, ya que puede dar causa a errores de inexactitud en ciertos valores.